# Prove that the set of Algebraic Numbers is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, natural-numbers

Please evaluate the following, and help complete the proof.

Let $R$ be the set of polynomials with rational coefficients, then 
$$R=\{P(x)|a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0, a_i\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

Given that $|R|=|\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}×\mathbb{Q}_1×\mathbb{Q}_2×...×\mathbb{Q}_{n-1}×\mathbb{Q}_n|$. Whose cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{N}^{n+1}$, $R$ is countable.

Now, let $\mathbb{A}$ be the set of Algebraic Numbers, then $\mathbb{A}=\{x|P^n(x)=0, n\in[',k']\}$. Furthermore, we can denote each set of polynomial in $R$ as $$P_1=\{P'|a_1x+a_0\}, P_2=\{P''|a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\},..., P_k=\{P^{k'}|a_kx^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+...+a_1x+a_o\}$$ where each index $1-k$ corresponds to the degree(s) of the polynomial. Furthermore, for each $i\in[1,k]$ we can conclude from the first part that $|P_i|\leq |\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}|$ since a subset can not be strictly greater than the superset it belongs to. Moreover, we can also deduce that for each polynomial in $P_i$ we have $\{x_1,x_1,...,x_1^i\}$ as one of the solutions followed by $\{x_2,x_2,...x_2^i\}$, and going up to $$\{x_{r\leq |P_i|}, x_{r\leq |P_i|},..., x_{r\leq |P_i|}^i\}$$

**Edit**

Now, from what was said above we can deduce $$|\{x_1^i...\} \cup \{x_2^i... \} \cup \{x_{r\leq |P_i|}^i...\}|\leq |\mathbb{N}_1×\mathbb{N}_2×...×\mathbb{N}_{r\leq |P_i|}|$$

Similarly, since $|R|\leq |\mathbb{N}^{n+1}|$ we can deduce $$|\mathbb{A}| \leq|\mathbb{N}^{n+1}×\mathbb{N}^{r\leq|P_i|}|$$

Therefore, $\mathbb{A}$ is countable.

Now what can I do to extend and complete this proof? I have a strong inkling I am going the right way without constructing a bijection. I want to keep it that way.

**Edit**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: R is the set of ALL polynomials with rational coefficients, right?  Your defintion and following statements seem to suggest that R is only the polynomials up to some degree $n$.

Comment: @Joe Good catch, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are countably many polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$.  That is because each such polynomial corresponds to a sequence of integers *of finite length*.  (There are uncountably many formal power series with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$.)  It's fairly easy to see that there are countably many sequences of any fixed length $n$.  A countable collection of countably many sequences is likewise countable.

Each polynomial has only finitely many roots so the collection of roots of polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is likewise countable.  But every algebraic number is a root of a polynomial in $\Bbb Z [x]$, so we are done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I was hoping you would suggest a fix for the proof I am working on. But, what you have said is quite enlightening. Regards

Comment: I'm lost in your notation.  I think you need two different indices for each polynomial -- one for the degree of the polynomial and another to denote where in the list of polynomials of degree $n$ your specific polynomial occurs.

Comment: I think that you could use your definition of $R$, if you index it by $R_n$, and you’ve shown that $R_n$ is countable for each $n$. Then you can say that since there are at most $n$ algebraic numbers for each of the polynomials in $R_n$, that is countable. Then use @Robert Shore’s statement that a countable union of countable sets is countable to finish your proof.

Comment: @RobertShore Perfect, I will be sure to add those. They will most definitely make it more coherent. Thanks for the input

Comment: @RobertShore Hello, I tried to fix the notation, and added some extra bits to explain what is going on with each step. Please have another look over it. Regards

Comment: I think it's pretty much correct.  You're basically taking some steps toward proving that there are only countably many polynomials of any given degree $n$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: @RobertShore thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept the answer. Regardless, thanks for your time!